# Клик по list-style-image или list-style-type

Tags: css

Здравствуйте. Можно ли javascript-ом поймать клик по "кружку" или картинке, заданной list-style-image, рядом с элементом списка? Сам элемент списка ссылка. Хочу сделать такое-себе дерево.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Простым путем обрабатывать клик только по "кружку" нельзя.

Можно исхитрится. Понадобится такая верстка:

```
<ul class="styled">
    <li>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <a href="#">I'm Murloc!</a>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

стили:

```
.styled li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
/* В Chrome маркер на вид получится как стандартный. В других браузерах - нет */
.styled li::before{
    content:"\2022";    /* Значок "круглый маркер списка" */
    font-size: 22px;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -18px;
}
```

и обработчик:

```
$('li').click(function (e) {
    /* Если кликнули именно по li, то... */
    if ($(e.target).is($(this))) {
        //Ваш код здесь
    }
});
```

Суть идеи: **.wrapper** займет все свободное пространство **li** и будет забирать на себя клики по контенту.
Псевдоэлементы **::after** и **::before** недосягаемы в javascript, поэтому клики обработаются как клики по **li**.

**[Посмотреть пример](http://jsfiddle.net/venzell/vtWsy/)**

**[Здесь](http://unicode-table.com/ru/)** можно найти номер в юникоде для разных значков. Нужный код имеет вид U+XXXX.
U+XXXX нужно заменить на \XXXX, поместить в свойство **content: ""** и, вуаля, свой маркер готов;